# A diversion from Invertibility

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, reflection

**Known Fact**: Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $g(x)$ be its inverse, i.e. $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$. If there is an $x$-axis and $y$-axis and we plot $y=f(x)$, then it is easy to see that its reflection on the line $y=x$ will be the curve $y=g(x)$.

**My Question**: Now suppose we have functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=h(x)$ for some differentiable function $h(x)$. My question is now that if we reflect the curve $y=f(x)$ on the curve $y=h(x)$, will the image be $y=g(x)$?

Comment: What does it mean to reflect along a curve that isn't a straight line?

Comment: The line joining the point and its image will be parpendicular to the curve along which the reflection is taking place and the point and its image will equidistant from the curve but on opposite sides of the curve.

Comment: I see... although this map may very well not be a function, because it could be multivalued. E.g. consider the image of $0$ under a reflection along an arc of unit circle. Is this fine for you?

Comment: Of course this possible of multi-valuedness do not occur in the case of reflection on a straight line. So i should find some condition on $h(x)$ such that the reflection along the curve $y=h(x)$ is not multivalued?

Comment: I applaud your instinct to generalize, but I don't believe the current formulation gets you anywhere. Consider $f(x) = x^a$, $g(x) = x^b$, and $h(x) = x^{ab}$. Then $f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = h(x)$, and everything's (infinitely) differentiable, but it's not clear that any obvious definition of "reflection in $y=h(x)$" turns $y=f(x)$ into $y=g(x)$. In particular, in the case of $a=b$, the "reflection" of $y=f(x)$ must be itself, which seems ... problematic.